# How do I improve the quality of a video produced from still PNG images?

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to create a video from a few hundred PNG images. The PNG images look OK to me, e.g. here are two in MacOS X Preview:

[image: two images]

They're about 1200 pixels square, 16 bit RGB, no transparency.

But my attempt to make a few hundred of these into a video is encountering the following problem - nearly every frame has this yellow corruption (artefacts?), that sort of blocky flickery stuff you see on poor quality videos:

[image: video still]

The ffmpeg command I'm using is something like this:

```
ffmpeg -f image2 -i /tmp/image-%07d.png -vcodec mpeg4 -vb 20M -r 20 poincare.mov
```

I've tried changing a few parameters, but I probably changed the wrong ones. Any idea which parameters I should be changing, and to what value?

Console output is:

```
 ffmpeg -f image2 -i /tmp/image-%07d.png -vcodec mpeg4 -vb 30M -r 30 poincare.mov
    FFmpeg version UNKNOWN, Copyright (c) 2000-2010 the FFmpeg developers
    built on Nov  9 2010 12:20:29 with gcc 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5664)
    configuration: --prefix=/Users/worth/OtherApps/ffmpeg/ffmpeg/../local/x86_64 --enable-static --enable-shared --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-libmp3lame --enable-pthreads --enable-libvorbis --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-libspeex --enable-libopencore_amrwb --enable-libopencore_amrnb --enable-libvpx --enable-memalign-hack --disable-debug --disable-stripping --arch=x86_64
  libavutil     50.33. 0 / 50.33. 0
  libavcore      0.12. 0 /  0.12. 0
  libavcodec    52.94. 3 / 52.94. 3
  libavformat   52.84. 0 / 52.84. 0
  libavdevice   52. 2. 2 / 52. 2. 2
  libavfilter    1.59. 0 /  1.59. 0
  libswscale     0.12. 0 /  0.12. 0
    Input #0, image2, from '/tmp/image-%07d.png':
  Duration: 00:08:55.44, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0.0: Video: png, rgb48be, 1200x1198, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
File 'poincare.mov' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
[buffer @ 0x101301ae0] w:1200 h:1198 pixfmt:rgb48be
[ffsink @ 0x101301d50] auto-inserting filter 'auto-inserted scaler 0' between the filter 'src' and the filter 'out'
[scale @ 0x101302090] w:1200 h:1198 fmt:rgb48be -> w:1200 h:1198 fmt:yuv420p flags:0xa0000004
Output #0, mov, to 'poincare.mov':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf52.84.0
    Stream #0.0: Video: mpeg4, yuv420p, 1200x1198, q=2-31, 30000 kb/s, 30 tbn, 30 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0.0 -> #0.0
Press [q] to stop encoding
frame=13386 fps= 27 q=2.0 Lsize=  536132kB time=535.43 bitrate=8202.7kbits/s    
video:535981kB audio:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead 0.028261%
```

Comment: Also consider trying the mjpeg codec, that works good for me.

Comment: Does `ffmpeg -f image2 -i /tmp/image-%07d.png -vcodec mpeg4 -sameq -r 20 poincare.mov` work?

Comment: @stewe Not really, same problem... :(

Comment: @yi_H will try to run with 264, got to find it first ...

Comment: @cormullion Please show the console output from your original ffmpeg command.

Comment: @yi_H ffmpeg use the x264 codec.

Comment: @cormullion Can you provide a link to one of the input PNG files? Does the output look as expected with ffplay? What player are you using to view the output?

Comment: Yes [Here's one](http://i.imgur.com/ALeNt)
Don't know about ffplay
Using Quicktime or Mac Quicklook

Answer (score 1):

With `mp4` FFmpeg should default to `libx264`

```
ffmpeg -f image2 -i /tmp/image-%07d.png poincare.mp4
```